# GROUP BY more than one field?

Tags: reporting-services, group-by

I'm wondering if anyone can help with a different way around my issue.

What I have currently is:

```
SELECT
       [ItemDescription]
      ,COUNT(*) AS 'Amount'
FROM _shl_SalesOrderSummary ssos
WHERE ssos.[ItemDescription] 
       IN (SELECT [ItemDescription] FROM [_shl_SalesOrderSummary]
       WHERE ItemDescription LIKE '%FFP3 DUST MASK%' OR
       ItemDescription LIKE '%EAR DEFENDERS%' OR
       ItemDescription LIKE 'SAFETY GOGGLES'
       GROUP BY [ItemDescription])
GROUP BY ssos.[ItemDescription]
```

This brings me the following results:

```
ItemDescription                          Amount
EAR DEFENDERS                             473
Ear defenders (helmet)                      1
FFP3 Dust masks (SPECIAL ORDER)             1
safety goggles                              1
```

My issue is, I need the date to be able to add a parameter in a report.

When this is added, I can't seem to figure out how to implement it properly?

e.g:

```
SELECT TOP 50
       [Order Date]
      ,[ItemDescription]
      ,COUNT(*)
FROM _shl_SalesOrderSummary ssos
WHERE ssos.[ItemDescription] 
       IN (SELECT [ItemDescription] FROM [_shl_SalesOrderSummary]
       WHERE ItemDescription LIKE '%FFP3 DUST MASK%' OR
       ItemDescription LIKE '%EAR DEFENDERS%' OR
       ItemDescription LIKE '%SAFETY GOGGLES%'
       GROUP BY [ItemDescription])
GROUP BY ssos.[ItemDescription], ssos.[Order Date]
```

My dateset turns into this when the date is added groups by date rather than all as one in the previous example:

```
Order Date              ItemDescription Amount
2014-03-15 00:00:00      EAR DEFENDERS    15
2014-03-17 00:00:00      EAR DEFENDERS    10
2014-03-19 00:00:00      EAR DEFENDERS    22
```

Any guidance or help would be appreciated - Thank you.

Comment: Seems you need to make dynamic query for that, Add `[Order Date]` Parameter to Parameters list.(Hidden) - And pass this Date.Value to DataSet or SP's Parameters. Here you will get what you want to achieve it.

Comment: Not sure if my question is fullu accurate - I understand how to pass the parameter for date etc but it's more so when I add the date into the query, it splits up the query from being grouped. 

(amended main Q)

Comment: what you want as output? can u pls edit your question again to show us.

Comment: I need my output like the first example where all items are grouped together with their Count as the second column, but I need the date included so the users can pick the date range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is fine. Now you need to group the dataset in the report on the ItemDescription field

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255263.aspx

Comment: It was just me being silly and over complicating it (I have just come to a small report from a huge several database report) -  thank you for the heads up, much appreciated.